# codeigniter update register based on date

Tags: codeigniter, timer, cron, jobs

I am developing a news application where users introduce news and the creation date gets stored and the news appears with a "new!" icon next to it. I would like to automatically erase the "new" icon when the news becomes old (let's say 1 week).

How can I automatically implement this feature? **I would like to update a field of a table (new for instance) based on "it is 1 week later than when the news was introduced by the user".**

Do I need a "timer" for every new register created? Do I need some sort of cron job to check wether a news is outdated or not?

How would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: why you need new status? you can display it with the time difference.see @AdrienXL solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your app works as you didn't provide any code, but you can do it easly in your view:

```
if(time() - strtotime($postDate) <= 60*60*24*7) //$postDate is the date stored in your table 
{
   echo "<div>new!</div>"
}
```

if you want to do that with a db field, look at how crons work :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
$news_time = strtotime($row['creation_date']); // your database record creation date
$a_week_ago = strtotime('-1 week');

if( $news_time > a_week_ago ) { 
// Your 'new' HTML here
}
```